# How can I cut a string that contains a url and add it to array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string, split

I am building doing a custom breadcrumb and I want to each LinkButton unique commandArgument url.

I have a generic string variable that is a url. The name of each subweb can be different and as long as possible the hierchy is not limited.

the String variable could look like this:

```
http://site/org/content/Change/Book/process/item
```

what I would like to do is to split the string variable and add it to a array so it looks like this:

```
http://site/org
http://site/org/content/
http://site/org/content/Change/
http://site/org/content/Change/Book/
http://site/org/content/Change/Book/process/
http://site/org/content/Change/Book/process/item
```

I have tried following code:

```
 private void AddBreadCrumb(SPWeb web)
    {
     var webUrl = web.Url;
     var linkList = new List<string>(webUrl.Split('/'));
     // etc..
    }
```

But it doesnt do like I want it to do.

Any kind of help is appriacted

Comment: what would you like to occur if the URI path ends with `/`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an extension method for that and some `LINQ`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ParseUrl(this string source)
{
    if(!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(source, UriKind.Absolute)) 
         throw new ArgumentException("The URI Format is invalid");

    var index = source.IndexOf("//");
    var indices = source.Select((x, idx) => new {x, idx})
                .Where(p => p.x == '/' && p.idx > index + 1)
                .Select(p => p.idx);

    // Skip the first index because we don't want http://site
    foreach (var idx in indices.Skip(1))
    {
       yield return source.Substring(0,idx);
    }
    yield return source;
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
string url = "http://site/org/content/Change/Book/process/item";
var parts = url.ParseUrl();
```

Result in `LINQPad`:

[image]

Comment: shouldnt the usage be var parts = ParseUrl(url); ?

Comment: @Obsivus you can also call it like that.but this is an extension method, in order to use `this` keyword you need to put that code into a `public` `static` class.

Comment: @obsivus, what will happen when the URI has a query string or fragment?

Comment: The use of the `yield` keyword would avoid the allocation of the result list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to do a something like below. Note the use of the `Uri` class built into the framework.

You could further breakdown the query string by key value pair if desired.

```
var breadCrumbs = 
    EnumerateBreadCrumbs(@"http://site/org/content/Change/Book/process/item")
    .Select(uri => uri.ToString())
    .ToArray();


private IEnumerable<Uri> EnumerateBreadCrumbs(string url)
{
    var raw = new Uri(url);

    var buffer = new UriBuilder(raw.Scheme, raw.Host, raw.Port);
    yield return buffer.Uri;

    for (var i = 1; i < raw.Segements.Length; i++)
    {
        if (raw.Segments[i] == "/")
        {
            continue;
        }

        buffer.Path += raw.Segments[i];
        yield return buffer.Uri;
    }

    if (raw.Query.Length > 1)
    {
        buffer.Query = new string(raw.Query.Skip(1).ToArray());
        yield return buffer.Uri;
    }

    if (raw.Fragment.Length < 2)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    buffer.Fragment = new string(raw.Fragment.Skip(1).ToArray());
    yield return buffer.Uri;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use your own method, but cut the first part of the url string first :

```
var webUrl=web.Url;
webUrl=webUrl.SubString(7);//removing "http://"
var linkList=new List<string>(webUrl.Split('/'));
```

Comment: `web.Url = "https://www.linkedin.com/";` *or* `web.Url = "ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/pub";` Instant fail.